# Argument not valid trying to INSERT INTO MYSQL Table?

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (! $con)
    {
    echo 'Could not CONNECT';
    }
    echo 'Connected to Database';
    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons VALUES 'Struan' , 'Smith', 13)";
    mysql_query($con, $sql);
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Output was:

> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/www/struansmith.info/index.php on line 18

Comment: use query as `INSERT INTO Persons VALUES ('Struan' , 'Smith', 13)`

Comment: Thanks great answer but now as I log into PHP Myadmin I cannot log in to MYSQL server because of error #2005. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### EDIT

I noticed you edited your code ([from your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21221725/1)).

Change this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons VALUES 'Struan' , 'Smith', 13)";
mysql_query($con, $sql);
mysql_close($con);
```

to:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `Persons` VALUES ('Struan' , 'Smith', 13)";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
mysql_close($con);
```

`$con` goes at the end when using `mysql_*` functions. Plus a missing a bracket `(` for your VALUES.

---

### Original answer

There are a few issues with your code.

A missing semi-colon at the end of:

```
mysql_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons ( VALUES ("Struan" , "Smith", 13)")
```

(and removed the `(` in front of VALUES) and you're using double quotes instead of single quotes for your `VALUES`.

Replace with:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Persons` VALUES ('Struan', 'Smith', 13)", $con);
```

Plus `$con` goes at the end when using `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated.

Use `mysqli_*` with prepared statements or PDO.

Please consult the MySQL manual on the INSERT function:
 - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html

And if you're still keen on using the (*deprecated*) `mysql_*` functions, visit Tizag.com which is a pretty good Website when it come to tutorials.

- http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlinsert.php

**Do consider switching** to `mysqli_*` functions using [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: You forgot single quotes instead of double (for VALUES)

Answer (score 3):

```
 "                                      "
 string starts here .... string ends here
```

and the obvious syntax highlight hint... that color doesn't look right, does it?

You can use `\"` with double quoted strings. But prefer to use single quoted values for  mySQL queries.

Note: the next compilation error will be a missing semicolon. Then a runtime problem, because the order of arguments is incorrect:

```
resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```